# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200b' and Regex fix attempt

Tags: python, regex

```
assert response == str_list_answers[elements_counter],\
                "{} != {}".format(
                str_list_answers[elements_counter],
                response)//error message on this line
```

what i have done to see the error:

```
print response.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
```

What did i see :

```
Would you like to schedule the \u200bbusiness meeting 2018-01-04 at 14:00 in california and invite clara?
```

What i have done to fix it:

```
response = re.sub('\u200b', '', response)
```

but didn't work
When i normally print doing `print response` what do i get:

```
Would you like to schedule the ​business meeting 2018-01-04 at 14:00 in california and invite clara?
```

How can i fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
response = re.sub(ur'\\u200b','', response)
```

I have checked:

```
response = "Would you like to schedule the \u200bbusiness meeting 2018-01-04 at 14:00 in california and invite clara?"
response = re.sub(ur'\\u200b','', response)
print response.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
Would you like to schedule the business meeting 2018-01-04 at 14:00 in california and invite clara?
response
'Would you like to schedule the business meeting 2018-01-04 at 14:00 in california and invite clara?'
```

Comment: Both `u` *and* `r` as string type? One of them does nothing.

Comment: what version of Python is running your script?

Comment: Version Python 2.7

Comment: So, maybe I didn't undesrstand well the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the regex pattern as a unicode string, by prefixing it with a `u`:

```
>>> s = u"Would you like to schedule the \u200bbusiness meeting 2018-01-04 at 14:00 in california and invite clara?"
>>> '{}'.format(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200b' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> s1 = re.sub(u'\u200b', '', s)
>>> '{}'.format(s1)
'Would you like to schedule the business meeting 2018-01-04 at 14:00 in california and invite clara?'
```